custom route Angular
I have an app with a select dropdown, where for each selection, I display a list of items. I want to create a custom, unique URL for each selection. For example, if a user selects "Option A", the URL should change to:
mysite.com/option-a

This pattern should apply to all options.
The goal is for users to be able to share these custom URLs. So, if someone navigates to mysite.com/option-e, the corresponding list of items should be displayed based on that URL.
I was considering using child routes, like adding another router-outlet when a value is selected from the dropdown. However, I wonder if there's a simpler or more efficient way to achieve this.
Thanks

The dropdown should have router link:
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/catalog">Catalog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

Then the route should be :
const ROUTES: Routes = [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginViewComponent },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeViewComponent },
      { path: 'catalog', component: CatalogViewComponent },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }
];

Please check working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-dropdown-f1iopk?file=app%2Fapp.component.html
